# How to solve the error ENETUNREACH in Nodemailer

Tags: node.js, nodemailer

I'm trying to use nodemailer to send email in my project, but I'm getting this error. Can someone help me to solve that and explain me why I got this error? I'm using node.js for running my project.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XfZUt.png)

The nodemailer is used to send email through smtp.office365

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: You need to add more information, code you've implemented, what error you get etc.